# Is immediately waiting for a thread to finish the same thing as locking the main thread? Android

Tags: java, android, database, multithreading, android-room

So I understand that we use new threads for potentially expensive actions, as to not lock the UI thread.  But my question is, for the following the code, since I'm waiting for the thread to finish anyways, isn't the main thread essentially locked?

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // heavy stuff like db query
            }
        });
t.start();
try{
    t.join();
}catch(InterruptedException e){
    //handle interruption
} 

//waiting for t.join() before anything else
```

Most of my calls are like this.  I am querying a data base and waiting for the data.  Could someone explain what I'm missing here?

EDIT: I realize now that you could still interact with the UI like click buttons.  Is this it?

Comment: Yes, if you're on the main thread, this'll block the main thread. If you think you can interact with the UI, you're mistaken about the timing of the `join()` call.

Comment: Basically, if you want to actually do something in parallel, you can't do a join or any type of wait.  You need to do anything that requires data from that thread either on the other thread, or by passing a message to the message loop on the main thread with the data it will need.  You can't wait for it.

Comment: So if, for example, onCreate, i need to query a data base and populate a view with the data, is there no way around this?  I have to wait for the thread to finish if I want to use the data?

Comment: @microflakes Typically your UI would support an additional state: "Waiting for data", with a `ProgressBar` showing or something. Then, when the operation completes, it updates the main thread with the results, and prompts it to change into the "has data" state. The worker thread could call `runOnUiThread()`, for instance.